# Socket.io create room with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io

I'm developing multiplayer poker game and I'm using node.js and socket.io with redis adapter.

I have some parameters for rooms:

`name: string` - Server Name, for lobby

`password: string` - Server password, for private game

`gameSpeed: boolean` - Game speed (fast, normal, slow)

`players: Array<string>` - Players names, which are in this room

`amount: int` - Amount of players can connect in this room

I can't find in socket.io documentation, such feature. 
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One option would certainly be creating an object like e.g.

```
var rooms = {
    room1: {
        name: 'room1',
        password: 'randomPassword'
        gameSpeed: true,
        players: [],
        amount: 8 // maybe rename to maxPlayers
    }
}
```

Once a socket is opened, you simply send the JSONified rooms object over if needed (don't forget to strip out the password). Before joining the socket into the desired room, simply check what you need to check (e.g. if players.length < amount // maxPlayers).

Also, in the players array, you might want to save a playerObject which, apart from player data, also holds a reference to the player's socket. That way you don't have to do a search through a whole list of sockets when you know you want to do something with a player in a specific room.

Finally, what I found helpful, when working on a socket.io server (though that was almost a year ago) was having an object with references to all the connected sockets indexed with some unique IDs I could easily work with (e.g. the user's uuid from the database).